# How to print Long text through php?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, mysqli

Rightnow i am facing a problem of print Long Text. In my database i have data in long text format and that field has around 2000 line of text so how can i print that.

I am giving here full code of my file please go through it and try to solve my problem

```
<?php
if($objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")){
$objDB = mysql_select_db("android");
    $from_date=$_GET['from_date'];
    $to_date=$_GET['to_date'];
    $time = strtotime($from_date);
    $time1 = strtotime($to_date);
    $fdate = date( 'Y-m-d', $time );
    $todate = date( 'Y-m-d', $time1 );
    $tmpdate="";
    $time2 = strtotime($tmpdate);
    $tempdate = date( 'Y-m-d', $time2 );
    if($fdate==$tempdate){
    echo "if block";
        $strSQL = "SELECT LessonText FROM lesson_details ";/*Here this field LessonText is Long Text*/
        $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
        $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
        $resultArray = array();
        while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)){
            $arrCol = array();
            for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++){
                $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
            }
        array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
        }
        $Jdata=(json_encode(array('lessons:'=>$resultArray)));
        if($Jdata!=""){
            $error_code=0;
            $error_massage="Success";
            $Result=array(array('Lesson_details:'=>$resultArray),array('error_code:'=>$error_code,'error_massage:'=>$error_massage));
            echo json_encode($Result);
        }
        else{
            echo "Else Block";
            $error_code=1;
            $error_massage="No Record Found";
            $Result=array(array('Lesson_details:'=>$resultArray),array('error_code:'=>$error_code),array('error_massage:'=>$error_massage));
            echo json_encode($Result);
        }               
    }
    elseif($fdate!="1970-01-01" && $todate!="1970-01-01"){
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM lesson_details WHERE UpdatedDate>='$fdate' &&UpdatedDate<='$todate'";
        $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
        $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
        $resultArray = array();
        while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)){
            $arrCol = array();
            for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++){
                $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
            }
            array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
        }
        $Jdata=(json_encode(array('lessons:'=>$resultArray)));
        if($Jdata!=""){
            $error_code=0;
            $error_massage="Success";
            $Result=array(array('Lesson_details:'=>$resultArray),array('error_code:'=>$error_code,'error_massage:'=>$error_massage));
            echo json_encode($Result);
        }
        else{
            echo "Else Block";
            $error_code=1;
            $error_massage="No Record Found";
            $Result=array(array('Lesson_details:'=>$resultArray),array('error_code:'=>$error_code),array('error_massage:'=>$error_massage));
            echo json_encode($Result);
        }       
    }
    else{
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM lesson_details WHERE UpdatedDate>='$fdate'";
        $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
        $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
        $resultArray = array();
        while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)){
            $arrCol = array();
            for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++){
                $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
            }
            array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
        }
        $Jdata=json_encode($resultArray);
        $Jdata=(json_encode(array('lessons:'=>$resultArray)));
        if($Jdata!=""){
            $error_code=0;
            $error_massage="Success";
            $Result=array(array('Lesson_details:'=>$resultArray),array('error_code:'=>$error_code,'error_massage:'=>$error_massage));
            echo json_encode($Result);
        }
        else{
            echo "Else Block";
            $error_code=1;
            $error_massage="No Record Found";
            $Result=array(array('Lesson_details:'=>$resultArray),array('error_code:'=>$error_code),array('error_massage:'=>$error_massage));
            echo json_encode($Result);
        }       
    }
}
else{
    $error=array("ErrCode"=>2,"ErrMsg"=>"Database connection error");
    echo (json_encode($error));
}
?>
```

Comment: what's the problem in echo or print???

Comment: No any problem but i want data in json

Comment: what is the output when you print json??

Comment: [{"Lesson_details:":[{"LessonId":"1","LessonName":"Introduction to ASP.NET","CourseId":"1","CourseLessonNo":"1","LessonText":null,"LessonAudioPath":null,"LessonAudioDuration":"0","LessonVideoPath":null,"LessonVideoDuration":"0","UpdatedDate":"2013-08-09 00:00:00"}]},{"error_code:":0,"error_massage:":"Success"}]..here you can see Lessontext is null.this is the output i get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find out the solution so i am sharing here
in my case it is the problem of utf8 encoding. so i have add following line below my select query
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')

Answer (score -1):

Something like this, I believe:

```
print $longtext;
```